# Show reduction process step by step

Tags: haskell

I'm doing exercise 1.20 from SICP in Haskell and wondering if there is a way to visualize the reduction steps programmatically? It should look like this: http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.20.

Insted of `"b is 6"` I want to see uncomputed (or curried) expression like `gcd' 40 (rem 206 40)`.

Sample program:

```
import Debug.Trace

gcd' a b =
    if b == 0
        then a
        else trace ("b is " ++ show b) gcd' b (a `rem` b)

main = print $ gcd' 206 40
```

Original definition of the problem can be found here: http://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/1_002e2.xhtml#g_t1_002e2_002e5

Comment: Programmatically, no. Or at least not easily. Haskell's AST is less predisposed to that kind of thing than Scheme's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [right way](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer) to do this is to use the `Writer` monad.  You can use it to add logging functionality to your code rather easily:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

gcd' :: Int -> Int -> (Int, [String])
gcd' a b = runWriter $ gcdW a b
    where
        gcdW :: Int -> Int -> Writer [String] Int
        gcdW a 0 = return a
        gcdW a b = do
            tell ["b is " ++ show b]
            gcdW b (a `rem` b)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let (result, logs) = gcd' 206 40
    mapM_ putStrLn logs
    print result
```

---

What this implementation does is wrap the GCD algorithm in the `Writer` monad, which is used for aggregating some kind of result over many computations.  Quite often, it's used for logging messages or outputting intermediate results.  Here what we want is to get the result and a log of each of the intermediate values of `b` in a pretty printed form.  Since each of the messages is a `String`, we want to build up a list of `String`s, which is why it must be wrapped in square brackets in `tell`.  The rest of the algorithm is basically identical, simply `return a` when `b == 0` and otherwise perform the recursion in exactly the same way as before.  The `gcd'` function just wraps up the `Writer` monad so that this is transparent to the user.  Then we can get the result and the log messages and print them out however we want.  The `trace` function is usually reserved for debugging only, especially since it makes use of `unsafePerformIO`.  Using the `Writer` monad lets you re-use this code without having to worry about it printing out the steps every time.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's rewrite your `gcd` function, and I'm going to get rid of `trace` for readability:

```
gcd :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd a 0 = a
gcd a b = gcd b (a `rem` b)
```

Notice that in this function (and in the one you wrote) we must know whether or not `b` is zero before we can give you an answer. This means that `gcd` is strict in its second argument. Reducing `gcd 206 40` should be pretty straightforward now:

```
gcd 206 40
gcd 40 (206 `rem` 40)
gcd 40 6
gcd 6 (40 `rem` 6)
gcd 6 4
gcd 4 (6 `rem` 4)
gcd 4 2
gcd 2 (4 `rem` 2)
gcd 2 0
2
```